# Weka cross-validation, models based on folds never build

Tags: machine-learning, weka, cross-validation

I'm trying to run a 5-fold cross-validated MultilayerPerceptron on a dataset of roughly 600 records and 960 attributes.

```
MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 50 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a
```

The status when I start the classifier is "Building model on training data..." and you can see the Weka bird start dancing in the bottom corner.

Eventually the output shows the time to build the model, and the Weka bird stops dancing.

Is there some problem with my dataset, or some other parameter I've gotten incorrect?

Is the @relation variable used for any particular reason other than to name the .arff file?

Do I need to apply a filter at the preprocessor?

Comment: The multilayer perceptron algorithm needs a lot of time for the calculations..maybe you need to wait.

Now I forgot all the params, but the time depends on them. Try to set less neurons and layers. And try to do a feature selection on your attributes (with 100 attributes or less the algorithm will be more fast)

Comment: @Nikaidoh I assumed the dancing bird in the corner sitting meant that the process had complete. I've run a test on 'Use training set' just to see if that would completely successfully and it does! So something must be wrong specifically with generating builds for folds.

Comment: I was able to get the models to build for folds by running a 'use training set' test first, and then running the cross-validation tests. Something fishy is going on.

Comment: I am getting very inconsistent success with this problem. I believe the issue has something to do with Windows (7) or bad Java installation.

Comment: Have you tried to do it programmaticaly? There is a lot of documentation on weka site that may help